# Flex & Bison make problems when using struct pointers as a union type

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, flex-lexer, yacc

I am in the process of trying to make a file parser using Flex & Bison. I wan't to use a struct pointer in the yacc file (union) and am unable to get it to build. 

In my yacc file **eddl.y**

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>     /* C declarations used in actions */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "eddl_data_type.h"

int yylex(void);
void yyerror (char *s);
%}

%union {
        float dec; 
        char* ptr;
        int num; 
        char str[100];
        eddl_variable_t* var;     //<----- Troublemaker
        }

%%

... grammar

%%      /* C code */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "eddl_data_type.h"

int main(void) {return yyparse();}

void yyerror (char *s) {fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);}
```

in **eddl_data_type.h**

```
typedef struct eddl_variable eddl_variable_t;

struct eddl_variable{
    char*           __name;
    char*           __label;
    char*           __help;
    class_mask_t    __class;
    type_mask_t     __type;
    void*           __default_value;
    handling_mask_t __handling; 

    eddl_variable_t* next;
};
```

and i am using the following **Makefile**

```
scanner: lex.yy.c y.tab.c
        gcc -g lex.yy.c y.tab.c -o scanner 

lex.yy.c: y.tab.c eddl.lex
        lex eddl.lex

y.tab.c: eddl.y
       yacc -d eddl.y

clean:
        rm -f lex.yy.c y.tab.c y.tab.h scanner
```

My build output is

> yacc -d eddl.y 
>   lex eddl.lex  
>   gcc -g lex.yy.c y.tab.c -o scanner  
>   In file included from eddl.lex:2:0:  
>   eddl.y:17:9: error: unknown type name ‘eddl_variable_t’ 
>            eddl_variable_t* var; 
>            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Is it possible to have such a data type in the yacc union? If so I have been unable to find out how one does this.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue. The union properties specified in the yacc file get compiled into **y.tab.h**. I didn't realize that my error was stemming from my lex file, as there I include the **y.tab.h** file but don't include the **eddl_data_type.h** file. Insuring that it is included before **y.tab.h** resolved this issue.

The top of my **eddl.l** file is as follows

```
%{
#include "eddl_data_type.h"
#include "y.tab.h"
```

Comment: If you are using bison, consider using `%code requires` in order to get `#include "eddl_data_type.h"` in the bison-generated header.

Comment: I had this issue also, and what Alex has written has solved it. rici's solution works too, but  `%code requires` is not supported by POSIX Yacc.